# ReactiveMongo force query to execute on slave

Tags: reactivemongo

Is there a way with ReactiveMongo to force a query to happen on a slave?

Currently I'm using slaveOk, but it doesn't guarantee that query runs on a slave.

`collection.find(query).options(QueryOpts().slaveOk)`

The documentation for slaveOk:

`/** Toggles SlaveOk: The query is might be run on a secondary. */`

Answer (score 1):

Reactivemongo lets you set the read preferences on the cursor.

```scala
import reactivemongo.api.ReadPreference

collection.find(query).cursor[BSONDocument](ReadPreference.secondary)
```

More information on the different read preferences can be found in the mongodb documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/